# Webpage to output serial command based on check box selection

Tags: automation, serial-port, html, openwrt

I need to create a webpage to send a command to the serial port based on the user selecting multiple checkboxes. The page needs to have (8) checkboxes labeled "Input 1" through "Input 8", and (4) checkboxes labeled "Output 1" through "Output 4". The syntax for the command to the serial port is as follows:

If a user selects "Input 1" and "Output 3" the webpage would send "CL2I1O3 T" to the serial port. The numbers after the "I" and "O" correspond with whatever number inputs and outputs are selected. The "T" is what completes the command.

The webpage will run on a TP-Link WR-703N Router running OpenWRT. The serial (USB) port of the router will connect to a 8 input / 4 output speaker selector matrix. I can control this device using PuTTY, but I need to make a webpage to control it if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not much of a web developer, but I suspect you will get a better response if you show some code you've tried.  Also I'm a bit confused - does the WR-703N have a serial port?

Comment: Yes- the TP-Link has a serial out. I have since modified the system to include a Startech Ethernet to Serial converter connected to the speaker matrix. Now I am in the process of figuring out how to send the string of data to the IP address of the Startech device. I have also changed the webpage so that (1) button press will send the string of data. There are other issues that I am trying to resolve in another post, which has the HTML code. - Thanks!